# Can you have 2 junction boxes on one 12/3 cable run

Tags: wiring

I have s question about junction boxes. Can i have 2 junction boxes on on cable of romex? One box is to give additional length and the second box is to provide power to receptacle. If i can’t i will have to run a new cable from fuse panel, cut out sheet rock, ect. Thanks for the help Dean

Comment: Are you trying to add length to an existing cable, or make room for a coil of extra cable?

Comment: I am adding them to an existing cable

Answer (score 2):

That is fine.  However the junction box must be accessible forever, without disassembling any part of the house, and you must be able to reach the junction box's cover without any tools.

You don't need to put anything at all (like a receptacle) in the junction box, but you are allowed to if the circuit is allowed to support it.

Remember -- if you are moving things around, there are certain legal minimum outlets and switches that MUST exist. For instance every point along a wall must be within 6' of a receptacle (along the wall surface, that is).  Every 2' along kitchen counters. Etc.  There must be a switch at certain (expected) locations. Etc.

Comment: Harper, thank you for your answer. I just wanted to make sure about having more then one j box in the attic on one cable coming from breaker box was safe and legal. 
Dean